# css style with :target, last even when target in URL is gone?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am currently having some img's set to height:0px;, and when its ID gets in :target its height increases to a optimal value.

As you can see i can only have one img visible at a time, because when one of them is in target the other one returns to height:0px;

Is it possible to make the :target properties act more like a toggle, so that i can have more img's visible at a time?
I then think that i would need a :target to make them height:0px; again.

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
img{
    height:0px;
}
:target{
    height:200px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#img1">img1</a>
<a href="#img2">img2</a>
<a href="#img3">img3</a>
<img id="img1">
<img id="img2">
<img id="img3">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Not with the `:target` selector, at least not by any standards-compliant means.

Comment: You could add check boxes in a few different ways to achieve the 'toggle' aspect in addition to your use of `:target` or use javascript, but `:target` alone can not do what you are looking for, that I am aware of.